# Phoenix, Does conn redirect stop all further processing?

Tags: nested, elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a controller where I would like to add facebook page id and access token to my database so that I can post on behalf of a user.

To do this, I need to make a GET call to facebook and then with the access token I have to insert into my database.

That means I have a nested case statement because there are 2 points of errors, from facebook call and from inserting into repo:

```
case response_from_facebook do
   {:ok, token} ->
       case Repo.insert(token) do
            {:ok, _} -> ... redirect the user
            {:error, _} -> ... show an error message
   {:error, _} -> redirect and show an error
```

This is ugly imo so I was wondering if I did something like a guard if it would stop further processing:

```
token = case response_from_facebook do
    {:ok, token} -> token
    {error,_ } -> conn |> redirect(to: user_path(conn, :show, user_id))
end

# Does it ever try to insert into the repo if an error occurs?

Repo.update ... etc.
```

This would make my code cleaner to understand / read but, i'm not entirely sure if redirecting would prevent an attempt to insert into my repo. If this "guard" is not a solution, how can I prevent a multi nested case statement which can be hard as heck to read?

Comment: Does `response_from_facebook` return an error that's easy pattern-matchable separate from `Repo.insert` errors (can you post the kind of errors it can return?)? If yes, you can use the new `with` macro to simplify this piece of code.

Comment: @Dogbert can you provide an answer / example? I've looked at the with macro online but it seems none of the examples actually show how the error is handled. Are you supposed to assign the result of `with` to something? The error from facebook is in the form `{:ok, %{"error" => %{"message" => message }}}` whereas the error from ecto is of the form `{:error, reason}`. therefore they could be pattern matched. However I'm not entirely sure how that's supposed to happen. (Should I branch an error inside a `with` statement? Should I assign the result of the `with` statement for further handling?)

Comment: Check out the example with an `else` block inside `with` here: http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#with/1.

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner way to do this:

```
defmodule SomeApp.FacebookController do
  ...

  def create(conn, params) do
    get_from_facebook
    |> process_facebook(conn)
  end

  defp get_from_facebook do
    # this is a function you implement
  end

  defp process_facebook({:ok, token}, conn) do
    Repo.insert(token)
    |> process_insert(conn)
  end

  defp process_facebook({:error, error}, conn) do
    conn
    |> redirect_with_error(error) # this is a function you will write
  end

  defp process_insert({:ok, _}, conn) do
    conn 
    |> redirect(to: user_path(conn, :show, user_id))
  end

  defp process_insert({:error, error}, conn) do
    conn
    |> redirect_with_error(error) # this is a function you will write
  end

  ...
end
```

No undesirable effects can happen with this factoring of the logic and it is much "prettier."

Even better if you break the majority of this logic out into another module:

```
defmodule SomeApp.FacebookCommand do

  def call do
    make_request
    |> process_response
  end

  defp make_request do
    # whatever you are doing to request from Facebook
  end

  defp process_response({:ok, token}) do
    Repo.insert(token)
    |> process_insert(conn)
  end

  defp process_response({:error, error}) do
    {:error, error}
  end

  defp process_insert({:ok, record}) do
    {:ok, record}
  end

  defp process_insert({:error, error}) do
    {:error, error}
  end

end
```

And then use it in the controller:

```
defmodule SomeApp.FcebookController do
  ...

  def create(conn, params) do
    case SomeApp.FacebookCommand.call do
      {:ok, user} ->
        conn
        |> redirect(to: user_path(conn, :show, user.id))
      {:error, error} ->
        # redirect with error
    end
  end

  ...
end
```

Obviously if you are updating an existing user, then you would wriote your command where you pass the existing user into `call` as a parameter.'

Please keep in mind my module and function naming suck because I do not know the exactly what you are doing.  Better naming is a must.

Comment: This may just be a matter of style, but try to prevent using `|>` when there are not multiple pipes. `redirect_with_error(conn, error)` is better than `conn |> redirect_with_error(error)`. Also, when you use a pipe, you should be using a value to start the set. `token |> Repo.insert() |> process_insert(conn)` would be better than `Repo.insert(token) |> process_insert(conn)`

Comment: I mostly agree with you.  However, I like to use the pipe operator to reveal high level work flows, which is why I used it in cases above where there is only 1 parameter.  That said, some of the other stylistic problems are due to copy and paste of the original ideas Terence presented above, ie. `Repo.insert(token)`.  Thanks for the input.